# React Native Modals remains opened when app is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

While using the application, if there is a react-native 'modal' opened. I need to explicitly close it before refreshing the app. Else it would stay open and I have restart the app to close it.

Comment: it happens to me as well ... you need to make sure that your modal is closed before reloading your app ... otherwise you have to restart you app to dismiss it

Comment: which react version are you using?

Comment: I am using react-native `version: 0.55.4`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is known bug which happens during development only. Don't worry about it, It won't happen in production app

Comment: you can also encounter this problem on production when you use codepush with `installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE` option

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug in react-native, more info [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17986#issuecomment-443072147)

Based on the discussion in the GitHub thread, looks like the solution is not to be expected soon.